# TikZ: Drawing an arc between two coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am up with the following:

[image]

Using the code given at the bottom.

Suffice to say, I don't really like the result: I wanted to draw this picture without explicitly calculating the circle and the lines going into and out of it. However, I just don't know how to draw that part-circle to the right (with $\theta$ in it), such that I...

- get an arc which is shaped like a circle,
- have it intersect the shown without actually crossing them, and
- have $\theta$ placed between the middle of the actually drawn arc and its center.

How could I achieve this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (a) at (-3,0.5);
\coordinate (b) at (-1,0.5);

\draw[solid,-latex] (a) -- (b) coordinate[at start] (p);

\draw[thin,solid,latex-latex] (p) -- node[left] {$p$} ++(270:0.5);

\draw[thin,dashed] (-3,0) -- (3,0) coordinate[very near end] (angleStart);

\node (interaction) [circle through=(b)
                    , solid
                    , draw
                    , fill=lightgray
                    ]  at (0,0) {interaction};

\draw[solid,-latex] (interaction.north east)  -- ++(45:2) coordinate[near end] (angleEnd);

\draw (angleStart) to[out=50,in=-20] node[below left=2pt] {$\theta$} (angleEnd);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. Especially with `tikz` since there are numerous libraries that could be used.

Comment: Are the coordinates of `(a)` and `(b)` given? Actually what are the given data and what do you want to automate exactly?

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thank you, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @percusse: Nothing as complicated as that. I think, my question was already answered below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suggest that you base everything on the center of the circle in which case the calculations can easily be automated with the additional TikZ library: `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`

[image]

You can set the angle and radius you want via:

```
\newcommand*{\ArcAngle}{60}%
\newcommand*{\ArcRadius}{2.0}%
```

Everything else is computed based on these. You can adjust these to get the specific result you desire.

Two other tweaks that I have defined below are to adjust how far the dashed lines extend past the arc, and how far past the arc the label is placed (as percentages):

```
\newcommand*{\LineExtend}{1.25}%
\newcommand*{\LableExtend}{1.10}%
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\ArcAngle}{60}%
\newcommand*{\ArcRadius}{2.0}%
\newcommand*{\LineExtend}{1.25}%
\newcommand*{\LableExtend}{1.10}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XValueArc}{\ArcRadius*cos(\ArcAngle)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YValueArc}{\ArcRadius*sin(\ArcAngle)}%

\pgfmathsetmacro{\XValueLabel}{\ArcRadius*cos(\ArcAngle/2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YValueLabel}{\ArcRadius*sin(\ArcAngle/2)}%

\coordinate (Origin) at (0,0);

\draw [thin, dashed] (Origin) -- ($(\LineExtend*\ArcRadius,0)$);% Horizontal

% Extend this past the (\XValue,\YValue)
\draw [thin, dashed] (Origin) -- ($\LineExtend*(\XValueArc,\YValueArc)$);

\node (interaction) [circle, solid, draw, fill=lightgray]  
    at (Origin) {interaction};

\draw [<->] ($(Origin)+(\ArcRadius,0)$) 
    arc (0:\ArcAngle:\ArcRadius);

\node at ($\LableExtend*(\XValueLabel,\YValueLabel)$) {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that. I already like that picture you put there much better than what I did...

Answer (score 18):

With pgf 2.1 cvs for the node `\theta`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Origin) at (0,0);
\node (interaction) [circle, draw, 
                     fill = lightgray] at (Origin) {interaction};    

\draw [thin, dashed] (interaction.0) -- ++(0:1.5) 
                     (interaction.60)   -- ++(60:1.5) ;

\draw [<->] (0:2.1)  arc (0:60:2.1) node [right,pos=0.5] {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like that, too; this (name.xx) syntax is new in 2.1?

Comment: I use it recently so I'm not sure. The new thing in the cvs version  is to use `node [pos=...]` with `arc`  operation.

Comment: actually it is not that new, you have the access on all nodes (it is just particularly useful on circle nodes).

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,-1)(3,3)
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
    \pstGeonode
        (-2.5,+0.0){A}
        (-2.5,+0.5){B}
        (-0.5,+0.5){C}
        (+0.0,+0.0){D}
        (+2.0,+2.0){E}
        (+1.5,+0.0){F}
    \pstLineAB[nodesepB=-1,linestyle=dashed]{A}{F}
    \pstLineAB[arrows=->]{B}{C}
    \pstLineAB[linestyle=dashed,arrows=->]{D}{E}
    \pstMarkAngle[LabelSep=1.15,MarkAngleRadius=1.5,arrows=->]{F}{D}{E}{$\theta$}
    \pstCircleOA[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]{D}{C}
    \rput(D){\tiny Interaction}
    \ncline[offset=2pt]{<->}{A}{B}\naput{$p$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do an ellipse arc, as mentioned in the first example in the tikz documentation (description is somewhat missing in "the arc operation"-section). you specify the xradius and the yradius in the last argument, connected by ' and '. `\draw (\CENTERx,\CENTERy) ++( 45 : 1 ) arc ( 45:0:1 and 2);`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to draw an arc *from the center* is

```
\draw (\CENTERx,\CENTERy) ++( 45 : 1 ) arc ( 45:0:1 );
```

Draws an arc *on a circle of radius 1* **centered** at (`\CENTERx`,`\CENTERy`), *from* (45 degrees) to (0 degrees).

[See here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66490/drawing-a-tikz-arc-specifying-the-center/66491#66491) for an example

Comment: Can you draw an elliptic arc with your method above?

Comment: I cannot.  The first parameter defines the center `(\CENTERx, \CENTERy)`, then what point on the circle to start and what radius that circle is `++(45:1)`, that it is an `arc`, and `degstart:degEnd:radius` of the actual arc to draw.  I would be interested to know if it is possible though.

Comment: Maybe with some coordinates scaling (different scales for the different directions) this can be achieved. I didn't try...