# How to draw an arc when the central coordinates are given

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I tried the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \coordinate (A) at (4,5);
 \draw (A) arc (-30:-150:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What this does is that it starts the arc from the coordinate A. Is there any simpler way to draw the arc, by using the central coordinates alone?

Comment: See [Drawing a TikZ arc specifying the center](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66490)

Comment: Move the initial point by the starting angle (`-30` here) say and by the radius (`1cm`): `\draw (A)++(-30:1) arc (-30:-150:1);`