# arc that passes from (B) having a center on (A), automatically calculates (AB) distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I want to create an arc which automatically calculates the distance (AB). Inspired by page 58 at pgf manual. But the code block `% \draw (H)  ++arc (15:60: $ (A) ! - ! (B) $);`  does not help much.

Namely I want one arc that passes from (B) having a center on (A). Any idea?

These answer actually gives a lot of useful information but I can not figure out.
[How can I compute the distance between two coordinates in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38473/how-can-i-compute-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-tikz) and [TikZ: Drawing an arc between two coordinates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54142/tikz-drawing-an-arc-between-two-coordinates)

[image]

```
 \documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

    \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-2.0cm,-2.0cm) grid (2.cm,2.0cm);

    \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
    \coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
    \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
    \draw (A) -- node[above] {$g$} (B) -- node[right] {$a$} (C) -- node[below] {$b$} (A);

    \filldraw [ color = green!10!white, draw=green!10!black] (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

%     \draw (H)  ++arc (15:60: $ (A) ! - ! (B) $);

        \draw  (5:2cm) arc(15:60:2cm);


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Αs a final result I want to create something like this

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you can use the calc library to make the dashed hypotenuse a little rotated via using the angle argument of `($(node1)!fraction!angle:(node2)$)` syntax. It means that the path is going to be drawn from A to B but then it's going to be rotated `angle` degrees.

Then, you can use a `let` operation and compute the distance and the angle. Then you can use it for forming an arc that necessarily passes from `(B)` and rotated `(B)`.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

    \draw[step=.5cm,gray!50,very thin] (-2.0cm,-2.0cm) grid (2.cm,2.0cm);

    \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
    \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
    \draw (A) -- node[above] {$g$} (B) -- node[right] {$a$} (C) -- node[below] {$b$} (A);

    \filldraw [fill = green!10!white, 
               draw=green!10!black] (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

    \draw[dashed] (A)--  ($ (A)!1!-10:(B)$) |- (A);
    \draw let                        % We initiate a let operation inside a path
            \p1=($(B)-(A)$),         % Declare a vector from A to B
            \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},   % Compute it's length, let's call it "l"
            \n2={atan2(\x1,\y1)}     % Compute it's angle with respect to A, say theta
          in                         % finish off the \p and \n register declaration
            (A) ++(\n2-15:\n1)       % Move from A to a point in polar form (theta-15:l)
                 arc (\n2-15:\n2+15:\n1)  % Draw an arc from that point that covers 
                                          % 30 degrees with a start angle of theta-15
             (A) ++(5mm,0) arc (0:\n2:5mm) % goes back to A and moves horizontally
                                           % to start an arc theta angle
             (A) node at ++(\n2/2:7mm) {$\theta$};  % goes again to (A) and places label
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Extremely simple solution. It's easy to explain the command? `\draw let \p1=($(B)-(A)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},\n2={atan2(\x1,\y1)} 
          in (A) ++(\n2-15:\n1) arc (\n2-15:\n2+15:\n1);`

Comment: @karathan Sure, in a bit, I'll add some more info.

Comment: @karathan Does it make it a little clearer?

Comment: Yes, your explanations are that I needed :)

Comment: Ιs easy with the current angle `\n2` to create the arc of the `\theta` angle?

Comment: @karathan Sorry, I don't get what you asked,

Comment: I wonder if I can construct the angle **θ**  `\theta` at point A using the `\n2`

Comment: @karathan See the edit. The last label placement is not needed and can be placed later too. I just wanted to use `\n2` while it is available.

Comment: For some reason  does not work the last edit with angle the message is: ...Undefined control sequence (A) ++(5mm,0) arc (0:\n2:5mm)...

Comment: @karathan My mistake forgot a semicolon before the addition

Comment: Now everything is working :)

Comment: Could you explain me the meaning of this order `\draw[dashed] (A)--  ($ (A)!1!-10:(B)$) |- (A);`
. I have seen the manual of pgf but i didn't fully understand the meaning of the `!` in the code

Comment: @karathan It's the first paragraph basically. Which part is the problem?

Comment: I try to understand this part  `($(Α)!-10:(Β)$)`

Comment: I see but what exactly is the problem? I don't have enough space here for the full story

Comment: no problem relate to this question. just trying to decode the command to use it elsewhere. One inline comment perhaps within the question it was enough, if you have the time.

Comment: @karathan Try this : `\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {A};
\node (b) at (2,0) {B};
\draw (a) -- ($(a)!0.7!(b)$);
\end{tikzpicture}` and play with 0.7 with different numbers to see how fraction modifies the length. 1 is the full length 0.5 is the halfway

Comment: I think I understand. When using polar coordinates, ie `:` then do not put `!` at the right, or I get it wrong?

Comment: After that example now adding `\draw (a) -- ($(a)!0.7!10:(b)$);` makes the path rotated 10 degrees after it has been calculated. Start with 0 degrees which is equal to not putting an angle and gradually increase the angle and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: okay. Now clarifying, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 7):

With PSTricks:

### Method 1 (with Curved Abscissa)

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,45,-90}]
        (-1.5,-1){A}
        (1.5,1){B}
        (1.5,-1){C}
    \pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=0.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{C}{B}
    \pstArcOAB[arcsepB=-1,arcsepA=-2.5]{A}{B}{B}
    \pstCurvAbsNode[CurvAbsNeg=true,PointName=none]{A}{B}{D}{\pstDistVal{.75}}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)(D|C)(C)
    \psset{shortput=nab,labelsep=-3pt}
    \ncline{A}{B}^{$g$}
    \ncline{B}{C}^{$a$}
    \ncline{C}{A}^{$b$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Method 2 (with PostScript `Pyth2` operator)

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=0}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,45,-90}]
        (-1.5,-1){A}
        (1.5,1){B}
        (1.5,-1){C}
    \pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=0.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{C}{B}
        \pstVerb{/Dist {N-A.x N-A.y N-B.x N-B.y Pyth2} def}%
        \pnode[A](!Dist 21 PtoC){D}\psdots(D)
    \psarc[origin={A},arcsep=-1](A){!Dist}{(D)}{(B)}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)(D|C)(C)
    \psset{shortput=nab,labelsep=-3pt}
    \ncline{A}{B}^{$g$}
    \ncline{B}{C}^{$a$}
    \ncline{C}{A}^{$b$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Method 3 (with rotation)

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,45,-90}]
        (-1.5,-1){A}
        (1.5,1){B}
        (1.5,-1){C}
    \pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=0.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{C}{B}
        \pstRotation[PointName=none,RotAngle=-12]{A}{B}[D]
    \pstArcOAB[arcsep=-1]{A}{D}{B}    
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)(D|C)(C)
    \psset{shortput=nab,labelsep=-3pt}
    \ncline{A}{B}^{$g$}
    \ncline{B}{C}^{$a$}
    \ncline{C}{A}^{$b$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Method 4 (with intersection)

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,45,-90}]
        (-1.5,-1){A}
        (1.5,1){B}
        (1.5,-1){C}
    \pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=0.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{C}{B}
        \pnode[A](1;21){D'}
        \pstInterLC{A}{D'}{A}{B}{E}{D}% E is not used but we have to provide a name for it!
    \pstArcOAB[arcsep=-1]{A}{D}{B}    
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)(D|C)(C)
    \psset{shortput=nab,labelsep=-3pt}
    \ncline{A}{B}^{$g$}
    \ncline{B}{C}^{$a$}
    \ncline{C}{A}^{$b$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Red alert**: For the sake of simplicity, I left the nodes `D` in the given methods slightly different. It is not difficult to make them identical.

Comment: setting the origin for `\psarc` is superfluous; it is already done by setting `(A)`

Comment: @Herbert: I don't think so. Try it by removing `arcsep`.

Comment: `\psarc[arcsepB=-1](A){!Dist}{(D)}{(B)}`

Comment: @Herbert: I have tried `\psarc[origin={A}](A){!Dist}{(D)}{(B)}` != `\psarc(A){!Dist}{(D)}{(B)}`.

Comment: Note: I will not append `%` (to remove a trailing white space) to the end of `\pstRightAngle` in this answer  because it will be fixed internally in the next update of `pst-eucl`.

Comment: @Herbert: I think `origin={A}` is needed to properly calculate the angle `DAB`.

Answer (score 7):

A good job for `tkz-euclide` with several possibilities.

First `\draw[dashed] (A)--  ($ (A)!1!-10:(B)$) |- (C);` is preferable (C instead of A)
With `tkz-euclide` the mark for the right angle is obtained with 
`\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=green!20](A,C,B)`

We can get the arc with `\tkzCompasss[color  = blue,delta = 15](A,B)`. We draw an arc with center A through B 15 degrees before and after B

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]

    \draw[step=.5cm,gray!50,very thin] (-2.0cm,-2.0cm) grid (2.cm,2.0cm);

    \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
    \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
    \draw (A) -- node[above](g) {$g$} (B) 
              -- node[right] {$a$} (C) 
              -- node[below] {$b$} (A);

    \tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=green!20](A,C,B)
    \draw[dashed] (A)--  ($ (A)!1!-10:(B)$) |- (C);
    % \tkzCompasss[color  = orange,length = 2](A,B)
    \tkzCompasss[color  = blue,delta = 15](A,B)
    % \tkzDrawArc[delta=15](A,B)(B)

    % \tkzCalcLength[cm](A,B)\tkzGetLength{rAB}
    % \node [above=0.5cm,font=\small] at (g)  { \rAB cm};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With

```
  \tkzCompasss[color  = orange,length = 2](A,B)
```

I defined the length of the arc

[image]

Another possibility is to use the more general macro `\tkzDrawArc`

```
\tkzDrawArc[delta=15](A,B)(B)
```

this is a special use of the macro because I draw an arc with center A from B to B but I define `delta = 15` to extend the arc.

[image]

Now each of these macros calculates the length AB. It's possible to know this length with :

```
     \tkzCalcLength[cm](A,B)\tkzGetLength{rAB}
     \node [above=0.5cm,font=\small] at (g)  { \rAB cm};
```

[image]

Comment: very good job, but now I'm confused .... if you want have a look here ... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102232/let-operation-vs-tkz-euclide-vs-pstricks